# Writing xml with php

Tags: php, xml

I don't know where my error comes from, i am new to xml and i need some help.
I want to write an xml file using php. I have the following php code:

```
<?php 
 $xml = array(); 
 $xml [] = array( 
 'error' => 'ERROR_ID'
  ); 

 $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
 $doc->formatOutput = true; 

 $r = $doc->createElement( "xml" ); 
 $doc->appendChild( $r ); 

 $parameters = $doc->createElement( "parameters" );    
  $error = $doc->createElement( "error" ); 
 $error->appendChild( 
 $doc->createTextNode( $xml['error'] ) 
 ); 
 $parameters->appendChild( $error ); 


 $r->appendChild( $parameters ); 


 echo $doc->saveXML(); 
 $doc->save("write.xml") 
 ?>
```

My xml file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
  <parameters>
    <error>ERROR_ID</error>
  </parameters>
</xml>
```

but the ERROR_ID text node doesn't show up in the file.What went wrong?

Comment: the problem isn't in your XML generation, it's in your array indexing. Switch on PHP's error reporting so it shows warnings, and you'll soon spot this kind of problem.

Comment: I don't think error reporting would help in this case, since the syntax is completely correct..

Comment: @JeroenOfferijns stricter error reporting would give "Notice: Undefined index: error"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First option: replace this line:

```
$doc->createTextNode( $xml['error'] )
```

With this one:

```
$doc->createTextNode( $xml [0] ['error'] )
```

Second option: replace this line:

```
$xml [] = array(
```

With this one: (and remove the first line)

```
$xml = array(
```